# Опасен ли мой метод проверки админа в сессиях?

Tags: php, сессия

В общем, имеется бд мускл с юзерами, в ней имеется столбец admin, который в свою очередь связан с таблицей этих обозначений, 1 - админ, 2 - модер, 3 - юзер, 4 - забанен. 
Собственно в чем проблема:
Есть страница личного кабинета, которая выводит функции в зависимости от статуса. Вот проверка на авторизацию:

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])){ ?> 
    <p>Обычный юзер видит это</p> 
<?php if($_SESSION['logged_user'] -> admin === 1){ ?> 
 <p>Админ видит это</p> 
 <? }
    } ?>
```

Если допустим я буду менять admin === 1, на 3(юзер по умолчанию), потом опять сменю на 1, то статус юзера меняется с 3 на 1. Т.е ему присваиваются админ права. Разъясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит? И безопасно ли это использовать, если не баловаться с изменением 1 на 3 и тд.

Comment: 1. Вроде очевидно. 2. Вроде да.

Comment: Очевидно?) Тогда я вопрос бы не задавал, вот это очевидно. А "Вроде да" Это ответ на то что безопасно ли это?

Comment: Очевидно. Ты получишь результат проверки в соответствии с тем, какое значение присвоишь. Второе - да, про безопасность. Насколько я знаю, сессия хранится на сервере, поэтому пользователь её подменить не может (ну, если других косяков в коде нет). Т. е. все подобные данные должны храниться на сервере и нельзя доверять данным, полученным от пользователя. Если это выполняется, то безопасно.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, просто очень странным показалось присвоение админ-прав на уровне сессий, когда в базе все стоит на своих местах.

Comment: Строго говоря, это небезопасно по той простой причине, что привилегию админа не может снять никто, кроме самого пользователя, т.к. она висит в его сессии (вариант принудительного пурджа сессии не рассматриваем)

Comment: @etki , если я правильно понял, то если я случайно поменяю значение привелегий, то пока человек сам не "убьет" свою сессию, я бессилен?

Comment: Да (но скорее вы специально захотите снять привилегии администратора, и в самый неподходящий момент это не даст никакого эффекта).

Comment: Лучше всего в сессии хранить `id` залогиненого пользователя, потом данные доставать из БД. В этом случаи админ сайта всегда может поменять любому пользователю привилегию. Не рекомендуется в сессиях хранить большие данные